# Send email once per day using pm2 and nodemailer

Tags: email, cron

We are using a `Ubuntu 18.04` server with `pm2` to schedule the launch of a `node.js` backend on startup and have a working `nodemailer` script that sends an email to our team members with the state of some resources on the server.

This script works if launched manually, using `node script.js`.
If it is started using `pm2 start script.js` it just keeps sending emails without stopping. I think that is because `pm2` keeps the script working by restarting it after it finishes. After searching around, I found the `--no-restart` option and I could run it only once with

```
`pm2 start script.js --no-autorestart`
```

Since the goal is to send emails everyday at 09h00 and `pm2` has integrated `cron` features, I tried running

```
pm2 start reportOfflineDevices.js --no-autorestart --cron "0 9 * * *"
```

but it did not send any email. After some more searching I found out that `pm2` only uses its `cron` features to restart running processes. Since I include the `--no-autorestart` option, after it runs once, it is listed in `pm2 status` as being stopped, therefore it won't be restarted.

Finally, I tried a naive approach of including a `while(1);` at the end of my script to keep it running but it won't even send an email and `top` shows the script eating 100% CPU resources. In hindsight, I guess that makes sense...

In the end I will have to either find a way to keep the script working without consuming CPU resources or forget about `pm2` and just use plain old `cron`. What do you think?

I post here a simplified minimum working example of my script (if correct server and auth are configured in the transporter).

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const moment = require('moment');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const report = async () => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        auth: {
            user: 'abc@server.blabla',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        host: 'our.server.blabla',
        port: 465,
        secure: true
    });

    var sendToEngineering = {
        from: 'noreply@server.blabla',
        to: 'engineering@server.blabla',
        subject: 'Report',
        text: "report"
    };

    transporter.sendMail(sendToEngineering, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return error;
        } else {
            return 'Email sent: ' + info.response;
        }
    });
}
report();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks really interesting and good, but what I would have done is to create it as an express application and add the node-cron package and then you could change the code as following:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const moment = require('moment');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const express = require("express");
const cron = require("node-cron");

// setup your express server as an app
var app = express();

const report = async () => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        auth: {
            user: 'abc@server.blabla',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        host: 'our.server.blabla',
        port: 465,
        secure: true
    });

    var sendToEngineering = {
        from: 'noreply@server.blabla',
        to: 'engineering@server.blabla',
        subject: 'Report',
        text: "report"
    };

    transporter.sendMail(sendToEngineering, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return error;
        } else {
            return 'Email sent: ' + info.response;
        }
    });
}

// start scheduling the execution of your function on a daily basis use
// https://crontab.guru to determine your timings
// don't forget that these times are ofcourse based on the server times so you need 
// to change it for your timezone
cron.schedule("0 8 * * *, function() {
    report();
});

app.listen(3129);

// next line is to ensure it executes atleast once when restarting pm2
report();
```

This way your report function should be executed once a day and if your server/app needs updates you can easily restart the server and receive a mail to ensure there are no issues.